# Jenkins CI - Github 2FA

Tags: android, git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins for my Android GitHub project, but since I have a GitHub account under two-factor-authorization Jenkins doesn't resolve my credentials successful and the git fetch just keeps on going until timeout (after 15 min). I tried with ssh private key, then with with a Personal access token, and of course also with normal credentials, but nothing works.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue on Jenkins? If I turn off 2FA on GitHub my repo is fetched normally, so it's definitely an issue with 2FA.

I also tried to fetch it with the new BlueOcean plugin (which is awesome) but the same issue occurs.

Comment: I have 2FA and can access my github repository in SSH with private key or with access token in HTTPS. Please provide your test protocol with both options and full errors output.

Comment: I'm testing it locally via HTTP, might be a case that SSL is required?

Comment: HTTP is simply redirected to HTTPS: `warning: redirecting to https://github.com/user/repo.git/`